# What exactly makes something (an event) metaphysically (i.e. not epistemically, physically, logically, mathematically) possible?

Tags: metaphysics

I take it that, for instance, an epistemic possibility depends in some sense on the cognitive (`as far as one knows something could be the case then this suffices to desribe it as epistemically possible). A metaphysical possibility is in the above sense independent of the cognitive, i.e. it must depend on something else (then the cognizing subject), presumably on the world as it is in itself. Thus, my question could also be put like this: What features of the world does a metaphysical possibility supervene on? I am totally unable to get my head around this. The only thing I can think of is that metaphysical possibility of an event has something to do with the world being such that the event is bound to happen at some point in the life span of the world. Please, help!

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the contributor.

Comment: Can you perhaps give us the passage or work this comes from for context?

Comment: Metaphysical possibility does not supervene on the way our actual world is, that would be nomic possibility, perhaps, what is allowed by the actual laws of nature. Proponents of metaphysical possibility do not offer cogent criteria as to what limits it beyond logical possibility, it is rather something vague conjectured to lie between logical and nomic possibility. Some candidate examples involve principles concerning mathematics, the nature of universals or physical/mental relations, but all are controversial, see [SEP, Modality](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/modality-varieties/#Dat).

Comment: @J D This doesn`t really come from any passage or work. I was just trying to formulate what exactly puzzles me.

Comment: @Conifold Correct, metaphysical possibility doesn`t supervene on the way our actual world is. What I meant (and formulated wrongly) is: what about a world makes something (in that world) metaphysically possible. Alternatively, utilizing the notion of a possible world: What makes a world a metaphysically possible world? And what do you think about my very hazy idea that the question could be answered in something like the following way: a world is a metaphysically possible iff it is bound to switch (at some point in time) from the non-actual mode of existence into the actual one? Thanks!

Comment: Zvolenszky suggests in [Naming with Necessity, pp. 3,15,34](https://philarchive.org/rec/SCHNWN) that "*metaphysical conception... is about how things might or must have been had things gone differently with respect to details of the actual course of history*". I.e. metaphysical modality is built around counterfactual claims about actual individuals, some of whose properties are declared "accidental". Then it makes little sense to ask what makes a world metaphysically possible, rather which individual properties we choose to count as "essential", and modal logic is indifferent to the choice.

Comment: @Conifold Thanks. I think I understand the answer. It makes sense. But the price is high (at least for me): metaphysical modality collapses into epistemological modality. Thanks again.

Comment: Epistemic modality is structured very differently, as *de dicto* rather than *de re*, and is built not around rigid individuals, but around descriptions, not affixed to individuals. The distinction was the centerpiece of Kripke's work. Of course, neither commits to any substantive metaphysics, but that is to be expected, modal logic would not be very applicable if it was tied to something as controversial as that. Even Kripke's science based essentialism proved too much for many people.

Comment: True. Thanks. Kripke`s distinctions related to metaphysics of modality are very important. However, as I understand him (and that might be what you are hinting at above), his metaphysics is ultimately grounded in science based essentialism, which feels to me unacceptable. I just can`t see how this is metaphysics at all, and am thus unable to use Kripke to address what puzzles me.